# Want to STOP Windows 7 from changing song names in my music folders

Tags: windows-7, mp3, music

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium. I have several subfolders in MY MUSIC. I want to be able to name the songs in any of those folders whatever I want and not have the names I changed them to changed by Windows 7.

Specifically, I'm trying to NOT have track numbers, NOT have bits per second info showing, NOT have wrong information or 'Various Artists' showing in a song title.

As an example, I just want this format showing and nothing else for all my song titles within folders within MY MUSIC:

Born To Be Wild - Steppenwolf

Not everyone wants to use automated naming via databases. I'm one of those people and I have
good reason to want the short, simple format for my song titles as in my example above.

If anyone can help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm not a computer whiz by any means so I can't do real technical stuff so I need a thorough explanation of how to get this done.

Comment: Windows 7 shouldn't be changing that automatically. I have a VERY specific naming convention, and if that happened that would drive me nuts. I wonder if your music player is showing file tags as well. What are you listening to music with?

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves the problem: (I'm assuming you're using WMP?)

1. Open **Windows Media Player**, go to **Organize>Options**:

[image]

2. Go to **Library** and uncheck Retrieve additional information from the Internet.

[image]

3. Go to **Privacy** and uncheck the first 3 options in **Enhanced Playback and Device Experience.**

[image]

This *should* prevent further addition of details to songs you add afterwards.

**NOW to remove metadata from existing music:**

**EDIT:** noticed that your musics are in subfolders. If there are too many subfolders then you can go to the root MY MUSIC folder and search by extension eg .mp3, and highlight all of them.

Highlight all the music files in your folder, click **Properties>Details>Remove Properties and Personal Information** and choose the attributes you want to remove and click **OK**:

[image]

I'm not sure why your attributes are all displayed in the same title, shouldn't they be displayed in their respective categories, like:

[image]

If they are displayed in separate categories then you can manually remove the categories, by right-clicking on any category and choosing only the ones you want to be shown.

This is for Windows8 but I think there should be something similar to this on Win7:

[image]